# How do i get user Culture in a HtmlHelper extension for MVC 3 .NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, cultureinfo

I'm creating a new HtmlHelper extension for my MVC 3 Application.
I need to get the Culture Info of the user viewing the page inside my new helper.

How can i get it??

```
public static class HtmlExtension
{
    public static string StringFor(this HtmlHelper html, string key)
    {
        ...
        //I need to get CultureInfo in here!
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer is "grab it through `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`", but by itself it won't help you.

Consider that your application has no notion of the "user's culture" -- the user talks to you through their browser, you are not on their system.

Now the browser does give you an `Accept-Language` header you can work with (Google will give you many hits), but [it's not recommended](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales) to use this setting to determine the user's locale because *in practice* hardly any users know about this setting and have customized it to reflect their preference.

The best approach is probably to unilaterally decide what the user's culture is (e.g. have `en` as a default, and give them a way to change it through the UI), store it somewhere (either inside session state or as a route variable) and push it into `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` inside `HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState`. You can do this inside `Global.asax` (example [taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478974.aspx)):

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["culture"];
    if (ci != null) {
        CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
    }
}
```

At this point, this answer becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy and you can access the culture through `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` from anywhere.